# Max recursion depth exceeded when adding parameters to celery task

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, flask, celery

Currently using Python 3.5.2 and Celery 3.1.23

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def test(self, player, team, region):
    print('test', player, team, region)

def update_player_accounts(self):
    try:
        teams = client.get_pro_teams()
        for team, team_data in teams.items():
            for player, player_data in team_data['members'].items():
                print(player, team, team_data['region'])
                self.test.delay(
                    player,
                    team,
                    team_data['region'],
                )
```

I'm iterating through a nested string dictionary `teams`. My understanding of this code is that I'm creating celery tasks in the nested for loop to print my parameters. The above code throws a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error. However, it works fine if I just remove one of the parameters in function `test()`. Doesn't matter which one I remove.

Also, the code will work if I attempt to add empty strings to the argument like so:

```
self.test.delay(
    player+'',
    team,
    team_data['region'],
)
```

Why does this happen? I'm only passing strings to the celery task which should be straightforward.

**Edit 1:**
Supplying example `teams`

```
{
   'Last Kings':{
      'members':{
         'Primoo':{
            'url':'/professional/resume/primoo/',
            'lane':'jng'
         },
         'Badmilk':{
            'url':'/professional/resume/badmilk/',
            'lane':'sup'
         },
         'Nipphu':{
            'url':'/professional/resume/nipphu/',
            'lane':'top'
         },
         'SryNotSry':{
            'url':None,
            'lane':'adc'
         },
         'Rakyz':{
            'url':'/professional/resume/rakyz/',
            'lane':'mid'
         }
      },
      'region':'las'
   },
   'Dire Wolves':{
    ....
}
```

**Edit 2:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 55, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 164, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 356, in pickle_dumps
    return dumper(obj, protocol=pickle_protocol)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jung\Documents\Projects\hq\services\player_service.py", line 84, in update_player_accounts
    team_data['region']
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 453, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 560, in apply_async
    **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 354, in send_task
    reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\celery\app\amqp.py", line 305, in publish_task
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 165, in publish
    compression, headers)
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 241, in _prepare
    body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 164, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 59, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\five.py", line 131, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 55, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 164, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "c:\users\jung\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 356, in pickle_dumps
    return dumper(obj, protocol=pickle_protocol)
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I've decided to post the entire stack trace as it is not that long.

Comment: Can you post a sample of `teams` that makes your code fail?

Comment: @AArias I've added an example.

Comment: I still can't reproduce your error, works as expected for me. I even tried with 2000 entries in `teams` just in case (all copies of the sample team you provided). For whatever it's worth, I'm using celery v3.1.19 with redis 3.0.6, although it probably has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error comes with a traceback which shows exactly which function was called by which other function. What does it say? (you don't have to paste all of it)

Comment: @zvone I've added the stack trace.

Comment: I was hoping for a repetitive traceback pointing at an infinite recursion. This traceback unfortunately is not complete. Anyway, just to test whether this really is infinite recursion, try `sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)` at the beginning of your script and see what happens.